# QueryBuilders based query in elasticsearch for searching text mixed with special characters(John-one) across multple fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use This query in my application for getting all matched records without special characters from across all fields of my database collection.Here I pass `q` value as run time search text`(John)`.Now problem is when I search for text`(John-One)` with special characters it's returns `0`.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilderForUserSearch =
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("active", Boolean.TRUE))
     .must(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("_all", "*" + q + "*"));
```

Here `q` is my passing text. It's working fine when I pass only text (like `John`) without special characters(like `John-one`). But I should fetch all records with special characters also.

Comment: @Eel Lee: Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, elasticsearch tokenizes the data at the time of indexing when special characters are encountered.

Try marking your fields as "not_analyzed". This will store your field value "as is" in index without tokenizing it. This will cause the side effect that your normal term queries, without wildcards will not work as expected.

Relevant mapping snippet.

```
{
   "field1":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "store":true
    },
    "field2":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "store":true
    }
}
```